# Recommend a light, open-source, in-memory DBMS based on C++?

Tags: open-source, c++, in-memory-database

I'd like to have an in-memory databaes, that is

- open-sourced
- written in C++
- light-weighted (as I'm to be maintain the code) and
- C++ code can easily access it calling SQL commands

I hope the speed is fast. Function-wise, I'm only looking into basic CRUD operations, stored procedure support would be a bonus.

Pls kindly recommend.

Comment: There is no such thing as a light-weight DBMS - in any language. A DBMS is a large-to-huge, and complex, software system. I would also not entertain the hope of maintaining the code of a DBMS yourself - that's not going to happen. Having said that, if you are interested on _working_ on DBMSes, maybe we should talk (it's my field of research). ... So, essentially, you need to change your requirements or settle for a "no" answer.

Comment: how could we talk?

Comment: Agreed. OP does ***not*** want to consider mainting the code (why would he?). So, the answer is probably https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Comment: @Mawg clarify: I do intend to maintain the code. That's why I'm looking into minimum code base and minimum function

Comment: ??!! Why on earth would you want to?  Surely it would be better to use a well maintained & supported solution like Sqlite and free your time for your applciation?

Comment: @athos: (1) Visit chat.stackexchange.com (2) Create an account (3) Enter the chatroom named "einpoklum_and_athos_2017" (4) Write me a message. I should be notified and show up (hopefully quickly, although it depends).

Comment: @Mawg let's say I don't trust nothing that's beyond control, such as Boost...

Comment: Then, as I said elsewhere, Sqlite is your answer, and you can get the source code [here](https://www.sqlite.org/src/doc/trunk/README.md)

Answer (score 2):

The closes that I can think is SQLite:
https://www.sqlite.org/index.html

But it has not all the feature you need.

Comment: mind to hint which feature(s) SQLite does not support?

Comment: The main point was "in memory". For which, see https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Comment: @athos It is written in C, not C++.

Comment: @athos would that be a problem for you?

Comment: @Mawg yes . I'm looking for something in RAM, not hard disk

Comment: See my comment 4 above this one - https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html  But, are you ok with is being coded in C, or do you insist on C++ ?

Comment: @Mawg I'm fine with C. how does SQLite manage the performance? for example MS SQL Server is faster than MS Access, because SQL Server can optimize the storage (on file), index, etc so that as an active RDBMS server is better than a passive file.

Comment: Google for something more recent thamn https://sqlite.org/speed.html  I am sure that you will find some good info